# iOS different default margins

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, margins

I'm designing my views both with a storyboard, and in a few .xib files for views that I instantiate programmatically. I also have some UITableViews, added from the storyboard.

I'd like to have consistent margins across my views. For now I have 3 different values:

- a value for my table views
- a value for the views I designed in my storyboard
- a value for the views I designed in a .xib file

Here is a screenshot showing the problem (left: .xib view, middle: table view, right: storyboard view):

[image: iOS padding inconsistence]

In the GUI builder, I always check the "Constrain to margins" checkbox, so that the margins are different depending on the device (which is nice). Having a different value for the table views is no big deal, but having different values depending on the way I designed the view (.xib vs storyboard) is really annoying.

Is there any way to have the same value everywhere, or at least in .xib and storyboard views?